# How to apply shipping charges if order is below X amount?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have enable free shipping from System -> Configuration.

If order is greater than 50 then it's Free Shipping.

But i want to charge if order is below 50 for X amount.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes

I gone through above link.

I want to set if order is above 50 then free shipping. If less then 50 then X delivery/shipping charges.

Thanks.

Comment: have you use Magento Shipping Table Rate? with the use of this you can achieve this thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi you can do this by Shipping Cart rules.

**Step1:** Goto admin>Promotion>Shopping cart rules

**Step2:** Create Shopping Cart rules

**Step3:** On this condition tab put logic shopping

```
Subtotal > = 50
```

[image]

and put below rules like screen shot
[image]

**Step4:** Enable  `Flat rate` from `System -> Configurations -> Shipping Methods`  and put your shipping Charges.It is work when subtotal less 50

Comment: I want only one at a time for example i want only flat rate if less then 50 and only freeshipping if more then 50 then?

Answer (score 1):

You can set that by using table rates in Shipping methods Section From the System Configurations settings,

Got to **System -> Configurations -> Shipping Methods**

Change the **Current Configuration scope** to **Website**

In Table Rates Tab Select **Condition** as **Price Vs. Destinition**

Click On **Export** Button Next to the Condition

Fill the Details in the CV downloaded,

And Upload it to the **Import** and save it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any tutorial link for this or example?. Because i'm newbie to magento

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping