# Flat rate Shipping is not applying on Not Logged In customers

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, shipping-methods

[image: Checkout Page Image]

Flat rate Shipping is not applying on Not-Logged-In customers.

But In Shipping Method *Highlighted* It is saying that KD 2 is shipping charge

[image: Configuration of Shipping Method]

I have added free Shipping rule according to this answer [Free Shipping Rule](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/51626/how-to-apply-shipping-charges-if-order-is-below-x-amount)

[image: Free Shipping Rule]